# set breakpoint based on output of function

Tags: c++, gdb

How to set a breakpoint in gdb depending on the output of a function which returns a std::string.

Say, I have two C++ functions:

```
void func_1(abc*) {
  ....
}

std::string func_2(abc*) {
  // Get a std::string from abc* and returns it.
  // Something like:
  std::string tmp = abc->getName();
  return tmp;
}
```

Now, in func_1, how is it possible to write a breakpoint only if the name of abc* is "Hello". I have tried this:

```
b func_1
cond 1 strcmp((func_2(abc)).c_str(),"Hello") == 0
```

This does not seem to work. What did I miss?

Comment: Not actually sure this is possible but I'm very interested. TBH I've always lazed out and just modified the code, but I understand that's not always possible (nor convenient). Being able to do this would be great.

Comment: @Hemant: Is the `func2` called within `func_1`? Is the breakpoint set at the point of the call? Can you post the definition of `func_1`?

Comment: @P.W, No. func_2 does not get called from func_1. The breakpoint is set at the function func_1 itself, not at the point of the call. Why do you ask definition of func_1? It does not really matter, right?

Comment: @Tas, Yeah, I could do the same. Writing out the code and put the breakpoint but as you said, it is not convenient. :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is possible. However, I'm quite sure that gdb supports [conditional break points](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html) which may stop only if a certain expression is true. Wouldn't this be sufficient for your issue?

Comment: @HemantBhargava: If func_2 is not called from func_1. I don't understand how a breakpoint is set in func_1 will get hit. Are you sure that func_2 will get called about the same time func_1 is executed?

Comment: "does not seem to work" -- it *should* work. You will probably get a better answer if you provide complete minimal example and a transcript of your GDB session. Versions of the compiler (and compilation flags), GDB, and OS may also matter.

Comment: @P.W I am not calling func_2 from func_1 at all. Please understand that question is about calling the function at the breakpoint itself.

Whenever func_1 get an hit, call func_2 with the same argument func_1 is getting and compare the values.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, No it does'nt. :) What else do you expect from an example. Actually there are already things which we need for this question. Setting an breakpoint at func_1, write in breakpoint condition that stop only iff func(2) returns "Hello". Calling function func_2 in the function breakpoint itself.

Comment: @HemantBhargava "What else do you expect from an example" -- an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If you are too lazy to write one, then I am too lazy to write one just so I can help you as well.